# Please help for my HTML and Javascript task

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to extract Class and IDs from a HTML document. I want result showing in `<textarea class="output"></textarea>` when clicking on SUBMIT button.
HTML:

```
  <div id="fullwidth">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="fifty">
          <textarea class="input">
            <div class="font step_footer">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="font-in">
                  <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <li class="col-md-3 col-4">
                      <div class="font-list">
                        <p>Notre équipeM<br> reconnus<br>obtient<br>istance</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </textarea>
          <div id="button-div">
            <button id="button">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fifty">
          <textarea class="output"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
  const main = () => {
    console.log(emptyInnerHTML(document.body))
  }
  
  const emptyInnerHTML = (element) => {
    return renderHTML(describeHTML(element)).innerHTML
  }
  
  const describeHTML = (node) => {
    return ({
      tagName: node.tagName,
      id: node.id || undefined,
      classList: [...node.classList],
      children: [...node.childNodes]
        .filter(child => child.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE && child.tagName !== 'SCRIPT')
        .map(child => describeHTML(child))
    })
  }
  
  const renderHTML = (tree) => {
    let node = document.createElement(tree.tagName)
    if (tree.id) node.setAttribute('id', tree.id)
    if (tree.classList && tree.classList.length) node.className = tree.classList.join(' ')
    if (tree.children && tree.children.length) {
      tree.children.forEach(child => node.appendChild(renderHTML(child)))
    }
    return node
  }
  
  main()
```

Result is coming when check on Codepen Console tab. I created a Codepen page for it. You can see it in this Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/BajJMav
I want to make it as result coming when I click on SUBMIT button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are missing several things here to make this a quality question. Properly detailed  explanation of precisely what this code is expected to do and problems you are encountering trying to achieve that goal. Both take a little bit more effort on your part in making this clearly understood for all readers. Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Working Code !!***

Observe inside the right output `textarea`, on clicking the `submit` button, you will be able to see the same result which were you see on load currently.

```js
const main = () => {
  document.getElementById("resultArea").value = emptyInnerHTML(document.body);
};

const emptyInnerHTML = (element) => {
  return renderHTML(describeHTML(element)).innerHTML;
};

const describeHTML = (node) => {
  return {
tagName: node.tagName,
id: node.id || undefined,
classList: [...node.classList],
children: [...node.childNodes]
  .filter(
    (child) =>
      child.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE && child.tagName !== "SCRIPT"
  )
  .map((child) => describeHTML(child))
  };
};

const renderHTML = (tree) => {
  let node = document.createElement(tree.tagName);
  if (tree.id) node.setAttribute("id", tree.id);
  if (tree.classList && tree.classList.length)
node.className = tree.classList.join(" ");
  if (tree.children && tree.children.length) {
tree.children.forEach((child) => node.appendChild(renderHTML(child)));
  }
  return node;
};

const onSubmit = () => {
  main();
};
```

```css
#fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fifty {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input,
.output {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button {
  float: right;
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #db4907;
  background: #ec350b;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#button:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullwidth">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="fifty">
        <textarea class="input">
<div class="font step_footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="font-in">
<ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
<li class="col-md-3 col-4">
<div class="font-list">
<img src="/img/font-img1.png" width="145" alt="img">
<p>Notre équipeM<br> reconnus<br>obtient<br>istance</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</textarea>
        <div id="button-div">
          <button id="button" type="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fifty">
        <textarea id="resultArea" class="output"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you make it as result coming in the right side textarea? (not in console)

Comment: I mean result display in <textarea class="output"></textarea> when click on submit button.

Comment: @Greetings: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: @Greetings See Edited answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="button-div">
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working.. Please check in https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/BajJMav